# Change citation label using multibbl package

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

I'm writing a document with two bibliographies, one for references and the other for links.  My code is in this format:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multibbl}
\newbibliography{R}
\newbibliography{L}

\begin{document}

Text, etc...

\bibliographystyle{R}{plain}
\bibliography{R}{References}{References}

\bibliographystyle{L}{plain}
\bibliography{L}{Links}{Links}

\end{document}
```

I would like the entries in the "Links" portion of the bibliography to have citation keys of the form [L1], [L2], [L3], and so on, while keeping entries in the References section with ordinary numbering.  How can I do this?  It seems that the`multibib` package allows for the style to be altered to accommodate this, but I was only able to get bibliography to compile the way I liked using `multibbl`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First here is how to do it with `multibib`, followed by an approach with `multibbl`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[labeled,resetlabels]{multibib}
\newcites{L}{Links}

\begin{document}

Text, etc. \cite{art} and \citeL{link}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{References}

\bibliographystyleL{plain}
\bibliographyL{Links}

\end{document}
```

To do something similar with `multibbl` in your set-up you can redefine the `\bibitem` command in the second bibliography to print a different label.  Here is one way:

[image: Sample multibbl]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multibbl}
\newbibliography{R}
\newbibliography{L}

\begin{document}

Text, etc. \cite{R}{art}, \cite{L}{linka} and \cite{L}{linkb}.

\bibliographystyle{R}{plain}
\bibliography{R}{References}{References}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{mybibitem}
\def\bibitem#1{\stepcounter{mybibitem}\@lbibitem[L\the\value{mybibitem}]{#1}}
\makeatother

\bibliographystyle{L}{plain}
\bibliography{L}{Links}{Links}

\end{document}
```

However, I would prefer to use the `multibib` approach or better still use `biblatex`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly in `multibib`.